# Angular binding input value to list item to check if it is same

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an array of 'word-pair' pairs which I am populating on my screen. Out of pairs, words will be populated in the left side list and on right side I am trying to have input field and when I enter corresponding pair value, checkmark should be shown.

[image]
**My controller**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.message='Welcome to Ionic'

  $scope.word_pair = [

  {'word':'Nitish', 'pair':'Patkar'},
  {'word':'Mihir', 'pair':'Janaj'},
  {'word':'Jannes', 'pair':'Stubbi'},
  {'word':'Martin', 'pair':'Wolle'}

  ]

})
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="row">

      <!-- Left half of the screen to hold list of words -->
      <div class="col col-50" align="center">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="item in word_pair">
            {{item.word}}
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>

      <!-- Right half of the screen to hold list of pairs -->
      <div class="col col-50"">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="item in word_pair">
          {{item.pair}}

          <input type="text">
          <span><i class="ion-checkmark"></i></span>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>

    </div>
```

How can I implement such an input field here? on  I can perhaps use ng-if directive.

Comment: can you add a fiddle of what you have tried?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/40AQO9?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
$scope.word_pair = [
{'word':'Nitish', 'pair':'Patkar'},
{'word':'Mihir', 'pair':'Janaj'},
{'word':'Jannes', 'pair':'Stubbi'},
{'word':'Martin', 'pair':'Wolle'}
]
$scope.partnerCheckList = {};
for(var v in $scope.word_pair){
   $scope.partnerCheckList[$scope.word_pair[v].word] = $scope.word_pair[v].pair;
}
$scope.showPartner = {};
$scope.partnerCheck = function(p,i_p){
   if($scope.partnerCheckList[i_p] == p){
     $scope.showPartner[p] = true;
   }
}

<input ng-model="pair" type="text" ng-change="partnerCheck(pair,item.word)">
<span ng-show="showPartner[pair]"><i class="ion-checkmark"></i></span>
```

I think this should work.

Comment: No it doesn't. It actually did nothing :|

Comment: I tried on your plunker. Above code is working fine.

Comment: Your answer is correct with little modification: instead of  if($scope.partnerCheckList[p] == i_p) itr should be if(p == i_p). Kindly update the answer! And thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can we move to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116693/discussion-between-nitish-and-neha-soni).